# Detect when input text change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input

I am trying to style an input and an ul-li like select-option (as style below). And I am successfully change the value of input text if I click on a li. For example, the #main value will be 1 if I click on the first li or 2 on the second li.

```
<div>
    <input id="main" type="text" disabled placeholder="Select...">
    <ul id="main-list>
        <li>1</li>       
        <li>2</li>
    </ul>
 </div>
```

Right now, I am trying to detect the value of #main input onchange so that I can change the content of #sub-list accordingly to the value of #main.

```
<script>
 var mymap = {"1": ["a1", "b1", "c1"]
             ,"2": ["a2", "b2", "c2"]
            };
</script>
 <div>
    <input id="sub" type="text" disabled placeholder="Select...">
    <ul id="sub-list">
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
    </ul>
 </div>
 <script>
 $("#main).bind("change", function() {
     // Reset the #sub-list
     alert($(this).val());
 });
</script>
```

The problem I am having is that I can't detect the value of #main onchange to reset the content of the #sub-list even though #main value is changed. Could any one help to explain the problem is?

Comment: Use `on` instead `bind`. Also `$("#main)` should be `$("#main")`.

Comment: Your code is wrong change `$("#main)` to `$("#main")`

Comment: Plus, `this` means `window` since it's not in an `onchange` attribute. Use `event.target` instead.

Comment: Sorry, it was my typo.

Comment: @NarawaGames that is just wrong. `this` refers to the element that the event was bound to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add your logic in the onlick

```
    $("#main-list li").bind("click", function() {
    $("#main").val($(this).html());
    $("#main").css('background-color','#FC0');
    $(this).parent().append('value changed');
```

});

http://jsfiddle.net/dshun/ud4r1p84/